# C# WPF не работает click context menu к DataGridViewRow

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
  <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu.Items>
          <MenuItem Header="Edit"/>
        </ContextMenu.Items>
      </ContextMenu>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
 </Style>   
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Click не работает

Comment: от того. что у вас контекстное меню есть в ресурсах, ничего не меняется. Почему вы решили, что то, что вы показали, должно где то и как то вообще работать?

Comment: @tym32167 оно в DataGridRow же

Comment: а, я пропустил `TargetType` в вашем коде. Тогда хз, ждем умных людей :)

Answer (score 0):

Для установки обработчиков событий контролов, находящихся в ресурсах или в шаблонах следует использовать `EventSetter`:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu.Items>
                        <MenuItem Header="Edit">
                            <MenuItem.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                    <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="MenuItem_Click"/>
                                </Style>
                            </MenuItem.Style>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu.Items>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```